# How to cut dataset into X and Y parameters

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, numpy

I have a time-series dataset that consists of evenly spaced timesteps and another parameter (say volume). I want to cut/split the dataset into X and Y parameters to train my ML model. I am looking for a logic/algorithm for Python that will be useful in tacking the simplified version below.

I have an array of even timesteps (1 timestep = 1day) ranging from 1 to 100:

```
                                            array = [1,2,3,...,100]
```

I also have come up with the following parameters: **N** and **K**. N to be used in X parameter and K to be used in Y parameter.

If `N = 5`, then on **first iteration** `X = [1,2,3,4,5]`, on *second iteration* `X = [2,3,4,5,6]` and on *third iteration* `X = [3,4,5,6,7]` and so forth. So, the **length of an X is equal to the number of N**. If `N = 10`, then on first iteration `X = [1,2,3,...,10]`, on second iteration `X = [2,3,4...,11]` and so forth.

K parameter represents the *length of a geometric sequence*. For example: `k =5` means `k = (1,2,4,8,16)`, `k = 3` means `k = (1,2,4)` and `k = 7` means `k = (1,2,4,8,16,32,64)`. Y parameter uses last element of an X array at each iteration and adds to it the values from the geometric sequence. So, the length of a Y is equal to the number of K.  If `len(K) = 5 -> len(Y)=5`, if `len(K) = 3 -> len(Y)=3` and so forth.

**Example 1**: N= 5, K=5:

*First step*:

```
                 X = [1,2,3,4,5]         and       Y = [6,7,9,13, 21] 

because K = (1,2,4,8, 16)  and Y = [5+1, 5+2, 5+4, 5+8, 5+16] with 5 being the last element of an array X
```

*Second Step*:

```
                 X = [2,3,4,5, 6]        and       Y = [7,8,10,14, 22] 

because K = (1,2,4,8, 16)  and Y = [6+1, 6+2, 6+4, 6+8, 6+16] with 6 being the last element of an array X
```

*Third Step*:

```
                 X = [3,4,5, 6, 7]       and       Y = [8,9,11,15, 23] 

because K = (1,2,4,8, 16)  and Y = [7+1, 7+2, 7+4, 7+8, 7+16] with 7 being the last element of an array X
```

`**Other steps**`

*Last Step*:

```
                         X = [?,?,?,?,?]; Y = [?,?,?,?,100] 
k = (1,2,4,8,16) because 100 is the last element of an array
```

**Example 2**: N = 6, K = 3:
*First Step*:

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5, 6]     and      Y = [7,8,10]   Because K = (1,2,4) and Y = [6+1, 6+2, 6+4]
```

*Second Step*:

```
X = [2,3,4,5,6, 7]     and      Y = [8,9,11]   Because K = (1,2,4) and Y = [7+1, 7+2, 7+4]
```

**Third Step**:

```
X = [3,4,5,6,7,8]      and        Y = [9,10,12] Because K = (1,2,4) and Y = [8+1, 8+2, 8+4]
```

`**Other steps**`
*Last Step*:

```
X = [92,93,94,95,96]; Y = [97,98,100], k = (1,2,4) because 100 is the last element of an array
```

**Edit**

I expect the function to look like:
`def dataset_split(array, N, K):`

It should return multiple X and Y arrays (basically chunks) based on the input array between 1 and 100. Basically it should go over steps and save the results for X and Y in a form of matrix or arrays. Based on my Example 1 above, my X array after first three steps will be

`X = [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,5, 6, 7]]`

and my Y array after first three steps will be

`Y = [[6,7,9,13, 21], [7,8,10,14, 22], [8,9,11,15, 23]]`

The procedure should continue until the last element of an array is reached which is 100 in this case

Comment: What should the function return?

Comment: The Function should return X and Y arrays based on the input values of N and K. If I go back to Example 1 with input N = 5 and K = 5 the function should return X array of size around (83,5) where 83 is the number of cuts and 5 is the length of each cut. Similarly with Y array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This satisfies your examples:

```
def split_dataset(array, N, K):
    k = 2**np.arange(K)
    
    # column stacking i-places shifted array for N columns
    X = np.c_[[np.roll(array,-i) for i in range(N)]].T[:-N+1]
    
    # masking rows that will go over the last value in array
    mask = X[:,-1] + k[-1] <= array[-1]
    X = X[mask]
    
    # adding k to the last column of X 
    Y = X[:,-1].reshape(-1,1) + k

    return X, Y
    
X, Y = split_dataset(array, 5, 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way to get all the values of `X` is to create a sliding window view into `array`. You can do this directly with [`np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
n = ...
k = ...

x = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(array, n)
```

The geometric sequence `K` can be trivially generated with [`np.logspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html):

```
K = np.logspace(0, k - 1, k, base=2)
```

OR

```
K = 2.0**np.arange(k)
```

Either way, you can pre-generate all of `y` as

```
y = x + K
```

Now you have two arrays with all of the data you need:

```
>>> array = np.arange(1, 101)
>>> n = k = 5
>>> x = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(array, n)
>>> x
array([[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
       [  2,   3,   4,   5,   6],
       [  3,   4,   5,   6,   7],
       ...
       [ 94,  95,  96,  97,  98],
       [ 95,  96,  97,  98,  99],
       [ 96,  97,  98,  99, 100]])
>>> K = np.logspace(0, k - 1, k, base=2)
>>> K
array([ 1.,  2.,  4.,  8., 16.])
>>> y = x + K
>>> y
array([[  2.,   4.,   7.,  12.,  21.],
       [  3.,   5.,   8.,  13.,  22.],
       [  4.,   6.,   9.,  14.,  23.],
       ...
       [ 95.,  97., 100., 105., 114.],
       [ 96.,  98., 101., 106., 115.],
       [ 97.,  99., 102., 107., 116.]])
```

The nice thing about this approach is that you don't need to copy the original data of `array` to make `x`, and everything is fully vectorized. Whatever operation you are planning on doing can likely be performed in bulk using numpy functions.

Comment: Thanks!, the vectorization will come in handy when dealing with large arrays/matrices